# Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed

Tags: node.js, docker, containers

I am trying to build the container from image , but I'm getting this error
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "-v": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
This is my docker file, I've created the volumes and networks
### STAGE 1: Base ###

FROM node:10.9.0-alpine as base

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app

COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

RUN npm update

RUN npm audit fix

COPY . /usr/src/app

### STAGE 2: Test ###

# FROM base as Test

# RUN npm run test

### STAGE 3: build ###

FROM base as build

RUN npm run build

### STAGE 3: Production Environment ###

FROM nginx:1.15.2-alpine as release

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY proxy.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

this is my run command

docker run --name njc -p 4000:80 -e NODE_ENV="development" --rm -d webapp-client:latest -v

3437518fe7ddfc628c6fdfecf6ce5a7ccd22562dc52c56fbd39940a3a6e277db

docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "-v": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS                                           NAMES

f5d6d44bc321   webapp-server:latest             "npm run start"          11 minutes ago   Up 11 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8000->3001/tcp, :::8000->3001/tcp       njs

721ee2e2cc2c   mongo:latest                     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   40 minutes ago   Up 40 minutes             0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp, :::27017->27017/tcp   njm

54d0e8c4c3ca   amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest   "/agent"                 29 hours ago     Up 29 hours (healthy)                                                     ecs-agent

Webapp-server container is up but webapp-client is giving error

help to get my issue solved.

Run ***docker system prune -a*** clear all cache and stopped containers